# Silverlight : Client requirements

Tags: silverlight, client-server

I am new to Silverlight. 
My questions are as follows

1. I know that Silverlight works with windows OS and Machintosh OS. But does it works with Linux/Unix?
2. If I run my Silverlight application on a server and access it through a client over the web, does the client need to have a Silverlight plug-in or its installer
3. With repect to the above point, what happens if I access the same Silverlight application through an Iframe from a normal HTML without having the Silverlight plug-in.

Links to your answers will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Moonlight is an option in linux.. and yes you can run silverlight apps in linux http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/
2. you will host you app on web server. and of course it will require silverlight plug-in to be installed on it in order to run the application on client.
3. no silverlight plugin means you can't run silverlight apps.. if you have plugin installed you can even run it in iframe.

Conclusion: in simple words silverlight app is nothing but follows the same requirements like Flash.

Regards.